# Java double multiplication giving weird result

Tags: java, double, game-engine

Currently writing a small framework that I have to use for a school project, more precisely, a game of Pong. I'm using NetBeans to code. I'm trying to make the ball movement speed frame-independent which if I'm not wrong is given by the formula

> New position = Last position + Speed * Time since the last frame

I chose to represent the ball's position using a 2D vector class I wrote (all it has is an x and y property and their respective getters/setters) so the method used to update the ball's position looks like so

```
public void update(double deltaTime) {
    this.position.setX(this.position.getX() + (this.speed.getX() * deltaTime));
    this.position.setY(this.position.getY() + (this.speed.getY() * deltaTime));

    this.texture.update(this.position);
}
```

When I run this the ball disappears off screen. I've only checked the X coordinate but this is what I got.

> newX = 300 + 5 * 0.025
>
> newX = -7.2444433823598585E9

I have no idea why this is and I'm completely lost. I've tried using the BigDecimal class but the result is the same.

EDIT: [Vector class screenshot](http://pasteboard.co/2wvpwKpm.jpg)

EDIT2: [Texture2D.update() and Test before and after setX()](http://pasteboard.co/2ww836i6.jpg)

EDIT3: Solved, the passed deltaTime was wrong in the `deltaTime = currentTime - lastFrameTime` because the `currentTime` was not initialized for the first iteration.

Comment: I think we need to see setX, setY, getX, and getY, are you sure you're not setting or retrieving the wrong field?

Comment: Imgur is blocked at school, here's a [screenshot of the vector class](http://pasteboard.co/2wvpwKpm.jpg), it's pretty straightforward though

Comment: Where you are checking the value of `newX` ?? Can you check before and after this code `this.texture.update(this.position);` so that we will know if this is causing some issue .. Are we need to know implementation of `texture.update();`

Comment: [Test before and after operation](http://pasteboard.co/2ww836i6.jpg) - Seems to be working with values of 50, which remains weird... and the texture update function calls Swing methods

Comment: Please create a small, running example showing your issue. Right now, it's impossible to say why it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you print all the values? Currently you are not giving any info about `speed.getX` and `deltaTime`, you are just assuming that they are correct. And I bet that one of them is incorrect.

Comment: Indeed, the deltaTime value was wrong because in my `currentTime - lastFrameTime` formula the `currentTime` was not initialized for the first iteration. Quite stupid of me but the E9 values really confused me. Thank you everyone!